# Laravel Transfer from main domain to third level

Tags: laravel

I have an CRM that was developed with Laravel. At the moment it's on one domain and everything works, but I need to move everything to a new hosting, new domain and run everything on a third-level domain:

Current: hosting1 https://crmsite.com
How it should be: hosting2 https://crm.site.it

- I made a copy of all the content and uploaded it to the root of the third level domain.
- I modified the .env file by inserting the address of the third level domain and replaced the mysql database parameters.
- I exported the mysql DB, changed all occurrences of the old urls to the new ones.
- I imported the DB into the new phpmyadmin.

But something is not working because I am getting a 404 error.

Where am I doing wrong?

Thank you

I thought that the steps I made were enough, but evidently it is not.

Comment: By 404 Error  do you mean the laravel 404 error page or the nginx/apache one?

Comment: @Aless55 if I type the new domain https://crm.site.it (this is an example address) it returns 404

Comment: This does not answer my question, but anyway, what type of webserver are you using? Are you sure the webserver is configured correctly?

Comment: @Aless55 I'm using a shared litespeed (so it should be the same as apache) server

Comment: I solved it by changing the document root of the subdomain from https://crm.site.it to https://crm.site.it/public

Comment: Please do not add resolved in the question. Either add the answer below or delete the question if you think it won't be helpful to anyone else.